# cannot import name 'urlquote' from 'django.utils.http'

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to login to the admin portal, however I am getting the below error. Please help I have been searching for solution but nothing

Exception Type: ImportError at /admin/login/
Exception Value: cannot import name 'urlquote' from 'django.utils.http' (C:_project\my-events\env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\http.py)

Comment: Which Django version are you using?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 6):

In Django 4, `django.utils.http.urlquote()`, `urlquote_plus()`, `urlunquote()`, and `urlunquote_plus()` are deprecated in favor of the functions that they’re aliases for: `urllib.parse.quote()`, `quote_plus()`, `unquote()`, and `unquote_plus()`.

**Downgrade to Django 3 to fix your issue.**
However, if you still want to use Django 4 and above, you can fix the issue by changing the reference of these functions. For your case, **add the following to the top of settings.py**:

```
from urllib.parse import quote

django.utils.http.urlquote = quote
```

Comment: My current version of Django is 3.2.12, also. I have the same problem, what can I do to solve that?

Answer (score 1):

Features removed in 4.0¶
These features have reached the end of their deprecation cycle and are removed in Django 4.0.

See Features deprecated in 3.0 for details on these changes, including how to remove usage of these features.

django.utils.http.urlquote(), urlquote_plus(), urlunquote(), and urlunquote_plus() are removed.